# Insert or update entry but fail on unique constraint violation

Tags: sqlite

Imagine a table like this:

```
+-----+-------+
| id  | value |
+-----+-------+ 
| id1 | val1  |
| id2 | val2  |
+-----+-------+
```

whereas `id` is `PRIMARY KEY` and `value` has a `UNIQUE` constraint.

What I want to do is to use a query that inserts or updates an entry based on its primary key *but* fails if the unique constraint is violated.

As an example, if I try to insert `id1, val2`, i want the query to fail whereas inserting `id1, val3` should update the first row.

What I however observed in sqlite3 is that if I use `INSERT OR REPLACE` to insert `id1, val2` it will replace *both* existing entries. I also had a look at the `ON CONFLICT` clause of sqlite, but there doesn't seem to be a way to distinguish `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint violations.

Is there any way to do something like this with sqlite or is there maybe another way to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating the table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   id INTEGER, 
   value VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE ON CONFLICT FAIL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(Id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
);
```

The key is to define different `ON CONFLICT` clauses for the different columns. `PRIMARY KEY(Id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE` will cause sqlite to replace the record when inserting a new record with conflicting PK whereas `value VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE ON CONFLICT FAIL` causes sqlite to fail when inserting a `value` violating the `UNIQUE` constraint.

This will update existing values when inserting new records with the same primary key, *but* it'll fail if you try to insert two records with different primary key and same value.

As an example

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, "test");
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, "update");
```

will result in

```
SELECT * FROM test;
1|update
```

but inserting the same value with a new PK

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, "update");
```

will result in `Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: test.value`.

Answer (score 0):

The [OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause uses *any* unique constraint, including the primary key constraint, to detect conflicts.

If the built-in behaviour is not what you want, you have to do it yourself:

```py
c.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET val = ? WHERE id = ?;", [newValue, id])
if c.rowcount == 0:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable(val, id) VALUES (?, ?);", [newValue, id])
```

Comment: It seems to be possible with the built-in behaviour. The trick is to _create_ the table with the respective conflict resolving like `value VARCHAR(32) UNIQUE ON CONFLICT FAIL, PRIMARY KEY(Id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE` and then just use the `INSERT` command.

Answer (score -1):

Jan, hope this will help you: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html